# Calculate SVG Arc between two points

Tags: javascript, math, svg, coordinates

[image: Desired status]

I've got points `X` and `A`, `A'`,... with coordinates:
`X [x,y]` (is the starting point)
`A [a,b]`, `A'[a',b']`, etc. (are the ending points)

I also know angle `XCA`, `XCA'`, etc.

I cannot find formula to calculate arcs, similar to ones on the picture, that connect point X with other A-points.

I tried to calculate radius X and radius Y using `abs(x - a)` and `abs(y - b)`. It looked good only when using angles like 90, 180, 270.

Then I tried to calculates radius of inscribed circle that cuts `X` and `A`. But arc still does not look "natural" while flowing from X to A.

Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: Image above shows somekind of desired status (I've drawn it using free hand). Gray lines are used just for positioning.

**EDIT ==========================**

I've found out that the inscribed circle option works quite well but I have no idea how to determine when to use `large-arc-flag` as `1` and when as `0` (same problem with `sweep-flag`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like quadratic Bezier curves would be the easiest solution. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400" version="1.0">
    <g transform="translate(200 200)">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="150" stroke="#000" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 106.066,-106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 106.066,106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 -106.066,106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
        <path d="M0,-150 Q0,0 -106.066,-106.066" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

The curves are defined by the path attribute **M*x*<sub>0</sub>,*y*<sub>0</sub> Q*x*<sub>1</sub>,*y*<sub>1</sub> *x*<sub>2</sub>,*y*<sub>2</sub>** where ***x*<sub>0</sub>,*y*<sub>0</sub>** is the start point (X), ***x*<sub>1</sub>,*y*<sub>1</sub>** is the control point (i.e., the centre of the circle, C), and ***x*<sub>2</sub>,*y*<sub>2</sub>** is the end point A.

If you want more control over the curvature, use cubic Bezier curves instead. These have two control points, which should be placed on the straight lines connecting between X and C, and between C and A. If you put them closer to C, you'll get a tighter curve.

[[JSFiddle link]](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4W5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I've tried quadratic bezier curvers as well but they did not look naturally connected to lines between inner and outer circle. Perhaps there is a problem with my control point.

Comment: If the lines connecting from outside the circle are pointing towards the control point, then the joins will be completely smooth. [Here's another JSFiddle with extended lines outside the circle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4W5/2/), and just for reference, [here's a drawing made with cubic curves that are a bit sharper than the quadratic ones](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4W5/1/)

Comment: Looks great. The answer is OK, but I still need to find my control point coordinates...given example is simplier than my actual problem so everyone could understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula for calculation all the arc's point between two points.

```
double x = centerX + length * Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
double y = centerY + length * Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

Where length will be the length from circle to your point. You can increase angle to +1 and get other point and stop till your end angle.